# EXCEL VBA - Multiplos cabeçalhos por página- um em todas as paginas e outro apenas na ultima

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, header

Preciso incluir mais de um cabeçalho por página no Excel:

[image: Linhas para considerar como cabeçalho:]

As linhas de 1 à 10 devem estar em todas as páginas com exceção da última, na qual devem constar apenas as linhas de 1 à 8.

Encontrei a sub abaixo

```
Sub RepeatRowsExceptLastPage()
Dim xPages As Long, I As Integer, xRg As Range
On Error Resume Next
xPages = ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count
Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select a row you need to repeat:", "Kutools for Excel", , , , , , Type:=8)
If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
On Error Resume Next
    If xPages > 0 Then
        With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
            .PrintTitleRows = xRg.AddressLocal
            ActiveSheet.PrintOut from:=1, To:=xPages - 1
            .PrintTitleRows = ""
             ActiveSheet.PrintOut from:=xPages, To:=xPages
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Ele permite a seleção do que quero como cabeçalho nas paginas com exceção da ultima, mas não consigo manter a seleção do cabeçalho que fiquem em todas incluindo a última pagina.

Comment: Seja bem-vindo(a) ao Stack Overflow em Português! Por favor, evite colocar imagens em posts e para mais informações, [leia este post sobre como não fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/165848).

Comment: Meu caro, não consegui entender esse trecho: "mas não consigo manter a seleção do cabeçalho que fiquem em todas incluindo a última pagina". E este é justamente o trecho que contém sua pergunta, o que impede nossa comunicação. Poderia explicar melhor?